# Mass importing CSV files into PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell, import

I have a directory full of .CSV files. I'd like PowerShell to import each file and store each as a separate variable. Currently I'm relying on a while loop and having the user manually input each CSV file by hand.

However, manual input is quite tedious and time consuming for the user and I'd like to have PowerShell automate this task. What would be the best way to go about doing that? I've thought about having PowerShell generate a list via "*.csv", saving that to a variable, and then looping over said list to do the mass import. Would there be a better way to pull off this task? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what may be better, rather than saving each as it's own variable, would be to import the files into a hashtable where the file name is the key and the imported data is the value.

```
$CSVData = @{}
Get-ChildItem '.\*.csv' | ForEach{$CSVData.Add($_.Name,(Import-CSV $_.FullName))}
```

Then, lets say one of the files was 'MarchSales.csv' that you wanted to access. You could simply reference `$CSVData['MarchSales.csv']` to work with the data. Want to work with data from each and every file? Something like this could work:

```
ForEach($filename in $CSVData.Keys){

    Do Stuff With $CSVData[$filename]

}
```

Comment: hmm, I've never worked with Hashtables before, I'll definitely look into them and try what you suggest. Right now I'm having the script look at specific headers in each CSV file to automate the tracking of change over time. I suspect you just showed me a much more efficient way to do what I've been doing. Thanks!